# Insertion error or pointer error in Binary Tree

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

When I try to add a number into my binary tree, appears the famous **Segmentation Fault**.

I guess the error is the pointer in function `inserir_no`. Maybe I should use a pointer aux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* create a node */

struct no {
   int info;
   struct no *esq;
   struct no *dir;
};

/* function prototypes */

void inserir_no(struct no *arv, int x);

void inserir_no(struct no *arv, int x)
{
    if(arv == NULL) {
        printf("foi");
        arv = (struct no *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct no));
        arv->info = x;
        arv->esq = NULL;
        arv->dir = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < arv->info) {
        inserir_no(arv->esq, x);
    }
    else {
        inserir_no(arv->dir, x);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct no *a;
    int valor;

    a = NULL;

    /* fazer um menu depois */
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    inserir_no(a, valor);

    printf("\nDADOS:\n%d", a->info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger in your development environment? With that you won't have to guess where the error occurs and knowing *might* help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is that the changes you made to `arv` in the insert function

```
if(arv == NULL) {
    printf("foi");
    arv = (struct no *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct no));
    arv->info = x;
    arv->esq = NULL;
    arv->dir = NULL;
}
```

don't change the passed-in pointer in the caller. What the function receives is a copy of the address stored in the variable in the caller, so only the copy is overwritten when you `calloc` memory.

To make the function change the variable in the caller, make it take a pointer to a pointer,

```
void inserir_no(struct no **arv, int x);
```

and pass the addresses of the pointers.

```
inserir_no(&a, valor);
```

in `main`, and

```
else if(x < arv->info) {
    inserir_no(&(*arv)->esq, x);
}
else {
    inserir_no(&(*arv)->dir, x);
}
```

in the recursive calls, as well as

```
if(*arv == NULL) {
    printf("foi");
    *arv = (struct no *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct no));
    (*arv)->info = x;
    (*arv)->esq = NULL;
    (*arv)->dir = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I have a question. When i use `(struct *no arv)` i not receiving the adress of the variable arv? Thank you!

Comment: No, then you receive the address of the location `arv` points to. Another option besides `struct no**` would be to have `struct no* inserir_no(struct no *arv, int valor)` and have the insertion return the updated node, then `a = inserir_no(a,valor);` in `main`, and you have to set `arv->esq = inserir_no(arv->esq, valor);` (ditto for `arv->dir`) in `inserir_no`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `a` right before the last `printf()` in `main()`, it's still `NULL`. You need to pass a reference of `a` to the function for the memory you allocated to be use able back in `main()`

In the function `inserir_no()`, you need to update to take a pointer to a pointer to a `struct no`:

```
void inserir_no(struct no **arv, int x)
```

In the function itself you need to update each reference to `arv` for a single deference:

```
if(*arv == NULL) {
    printf("foi");
    *arv = (struct no *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct no));
    (*arv)->info = x;
    //... and the rest, just didn't want to finish it off
```

Then In `main()` you pass the address of your struct:

```
inserir_no(&a, valor);
```

Two other notes for you:

1. You have a memory leak right now, you need to `free()` your allocated memory before you leave
2. You don't need the extra prototype if the function is declared before it's used. (in this case you declared it at the top, then used it below in `main()` so that's unneeded)

Answer (score 0):

call as `inserir_no(&a, valor);`

and change the signature of function to  `inserir_no(struct no **arv , int x)`

then it will work because of passing address rather than value of pointer.

`*arv` will be the `pointer to struct no`so use that at every place instead of only `arv`